# ls -ltr and ls -lt inside an sftp session are giving the same sort order

Tags: linux, macos, sftp

I am using `sftp` from a Mac to a linux server. The directory of interest contains several files named `file_*datetimestamp*` that were created on different datetimes in addition to files named `file_event_*datetimestamp*`

When I sftp to that server and I use:

```
sftp> ls -ltr file_*
```

or

```
sftp> ls -lt file_*
```

for some reason I am getting the same sort order regardless of the `-r` flag.

When I `sftp` from a mac to another mac and try the same commands,
the results are in the expected sort order.

Is this a known difference in how `ls` inside mac vs linux `sftp` session behaves?

Comment: The sorting is done locally. So it does not matter to what server are you connecting. It is also unlikely relevant if you run `sftp` on Mac or Linux. More likely, your local versions of OpenSSH differ. What are they?

Comment: I can not reproduce this using the default `sftp` shipped with macOS (OpenSSH_8.6p1) or the `sftp` from the `openssh` Homebrew package (OpenSSH_9.0p1). I tested connecting to a Ubuntu system running OpenSSH_8.2p1, and also to an OpenBSD system running OpenSSH_9.0.

Comment: Possibly one of the systems has `ls` aliased with extra options that conflict with the ones you supply.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant You cannot alias `sftp` commands.

Comment: Just a side note, make sure you understand that `-t` does not sort by the timestamps in the file names. It sorts by the file metadata timestamps.

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl - the timestamp I want is the one you see with ls -l not part of the filename (sorry that was unclear).  Kusalananda, thanks for checking, sorting is working if I use the same mac and sftp into another mac. It's not working when I go from the mac to this external linux box (don't know what distro is on it unfortunately)